# Image-picker not displaying the result photo react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I'm learning to code in react-native, I'm using in this code the library Image-picker for taking photos or loading images from gallery. When I take a photo, the image view is set with a blank white image!

Can someone review this code (I followed a tutorial online)
My current setup is:

- "react": "17.0.2",
- "react-native": "^0.66.4",
- "react-native-image-picker": "^4.6.0"

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Platform,
  PermissionsAndroid,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  launchCamera,
  launchImageLibrary
} from 'react-native-image-picker';

const App = () => {
  const [filePath, setFilePath] = useState({});

  const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
          {
            title: 'Camera Permission',
            message: 'App needs camera permission',
          },
        );
        // If CAMERA Permission is granted
        return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        return false;
      }
    } else return true;
  };

  const requestExternalWritePermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
          {
            title: 'External Storage Write Permission',
            message: 'App needs write permission',
          },
        );
        // If WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission is granted
        return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        alert('Write permission err', err);
      }
      return false;
    } else return true;
  };

  const captureImage = async (type) => {
    let options = {
      mediaType: type,
      maxWidth: 300,
      maxHeight: 550,
      quality: 1,
      videoQuality: 'low',
      durationLimit: 30, //Video max duration in seconds
      saveToPhotos: true,
    };
    let isCameraPermitted = await requestCameraPermission();
    let isStoragePermitted = await requestExternalWritePermission();
    if (isCameraPermitted && isStoragePermitted) {
      launchCamera(options, (response) => {
        console.log('Response = ', response);

        if (response.didCancel) {
          alert('User cancelled camera picker');
          return;
        } else if (response.errorCode == 'camera_unavailable') {
          alert('Camera not available on device');
          return;
        } else if (response.errorCode == 'permission') {
          alert('Permission not satisfied');
          return;
        } else if (response.errorCode == 'others') {
          alert(response.errorMessage);
          return;
        }
        console.log('base64 -> ', response.base64);
        console.log('uri -> ', response.uri);
        console.log('width -> ', response.width);
        console.log('height -> ', response.height);
        console.log('fileSize -> ', response.fileSize);
        console.log('type -> ', response.type);
        console.log('fileName -> ', response.fileName);
        setFilePath(response);
      });
    }
  };

const chooseFile = (type) => {
    let options = {
      mediaType: type,
      maxWidth: 300,
      maxHeight: 550,
      quality: 1,
    };
    launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        alert('User cancelled camera picker');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'camera_unavailable') {
        alert('Camera not available on device');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'permission') {
        alert('Permission not satisfied');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'others') {
        alert(response.errorMessage);
        return;
      }
      console.log('base64 -> ', response.base64);
      console.log('uri -> ', response.uri);
      console.log('width -> ', response.width);
      console.log('height -> ', response.height);
      console.log('fileSize -> ', response.fileSize);
      console.log('type -> ', response.type);
      console.log('fileName -> ', response.fileName);
      setFilePath(response);
    });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>
        Example of Image Picker in React Native
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* <Image
          source={{
            uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + filePath.data,
          }}
          style={styles.imageStyle}
        /> */}
        <Image
          source={{uri: filePath.uri}}
          style={styles.imageStyle}
        />
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{filePath.uri}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
          onPress={() => captureImage('photo')}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
            Launch Camera for Image
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
          onPress={() => captureImage('video')}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
            Launch Camera for Video
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
          onPress={() => chooseFile('photo')}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Choose Image</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
          onPress={() => chooseFile('video')}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Choose Video</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 22,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 20,
  },
  textStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 5,
    marginVertical: 10,
    width: 250,
  },
  imageStyle: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    margin: 5,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using react-native-image-picker@4.6.0

```
chooseImage = (type) => {

    let options = {
        mediaType: type,
        maxWidth: 300,
        maxHeight: 550,
        quality: 1,
    };

    launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {

        if (response.didCancel) {
            alert('User cancelled camera picker');
            return;
        } else if (response.errorCode == 'camera_unavailable') {
            alert('Camera not available on device');
            return;
        } else if (response.errorCode == 'permission') {
            alert('Permission not satisfied');
            return;
        } else if (response.errorCode == 'others') {
            alert(response.errorMessage);
            return;
        }else{

            response.assets.map((asset) => {

                console.log('uri -> ', asset.uri);

                this.setState({
                    imageUri: asset.uri,
                })

            });
        }

    });
};

render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.chooseImage('photo')}>
                    <Icon  name="images-outline" size={25}  />
                    <Text >Library </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        
            <View style={{marginTop: 50}}>
                {this.state.imageUri ? (
                    <Image source={{ uri: this.state.imageUri }} style={{width: 80, height: 80}} />
                    ) : (
                    <Icon name="add-circle-outline" size={40} />
                )}
            </View>
        
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test this code on my side

Comment: whats quality: 1 means here. I want to compress the size and no quality key is provided in options in my code